# Need to get first successful completion date from completions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, top-n

My data looks like this:

```
StuId StuName Exam Attempt Score
1       Sam   Eng  1       45
1       Sam   Eng  2       58
1       Sam   Eng  3       63
2       Mat   Eng  1       65
2       Mat   Eng  2       75
```

The student has passed if he has gotten above 60. I would want  to fetch first successful attempt for each student and ignore all other attempts
My expected result set looks like this:

```
StuId   StuName Exam Attempt Score
       
     1       Sam   Eng  3       63
     2       Mat   Eng  1       65
```

Is there a way I can achieve this in SQL Server?

Comment: There is no current attempt. For Sam the last attempt was attempt 3 and for Mat the last attempt was attempt 2. N number of attempts can be taken by each,even if they pass.

Comment: I believe, What is your current attempt?  = What have you done till now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `where` clause to filter out the unsuccessful attempts, and then use `row_number` to assign an identifier to each attempt, per student, and pick the first one:

```sql
SELECT StuId, StuName, Exam, Attempt, Score
FROM   (SELECT StuId, StuName, Exam, Attempt, Score,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StuId, Exam ORDER BY Attempt) AS rn
        FROM   exams
        WHERE  Score >= 60) t
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use aggregation for this:

```
select stuid, stuname, 
       max(exam) keep (dense_rank first order by attempt) as exam,
       min(attempt),
       max(score) keep (dense_rank first order by attempt) as score
from exams
where score >= 60;
```

The `keep` syntax is Oracle's (fancy?  verbose?) way of implementing a "first" aggregation function.